# Find the solution of this Laplace eq

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I need to solve the Laplace equation in two dimensions, $\nabla ^2 \phi(x,y) = 0$, $0<x<a, 0<y<b$ subject to $4$ boundary conditions:

$$\phi(0,y) = 0$$
$$\phi(a,y) = f(y)$$
$$\phi(x,b) = 0$$
$$\phi(x,0) = h(x)$$

Now, I have tried to really solve the differential equation, using separation of variable. Thinking that maybe I would need to use Fourier series. But the things got really messy, and so I have given up.

I am thinking that maybe the solutions have something to do with writing $\phi$ as some combination of the function $f(y)$ and $h(x)$, but yet I am not finding anything.

So, how to solve it?

Comment: One suggestion is that you can solve the problem where $f(y)=0$ but $h(x)$ is considered and call this $\phi_1$. Then solve the problem with $h(x)=0$ but $f(y)$ considered and call this $\phi_2$. The function you want will be $\phi=\phi_1+\phi_2$.

Comment: @podki Got it. That's true, thank you. I will try